# Django Multiple template inheritance

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, jinja2

My case is quite simple:

- I have a template for text/plain mails : body.txt
- Another one for text/html mails : body.html

The content of this two mail are the same because I use EmailAlternative to send both in the same mail.

**body.txt**:

```
{% block message %}{% endblock %}

{{ site_name }} team
-----------------
If you need help contact use at {{ support_mail }}
```

**body.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{% filter linebreaksbr %}{% block message %}{% endblock %}{% endfilter %}</p>
        <p><strong>{{ site_name }} team</strong></p>
        <hr/>
        If you need help contact use at <a href="mailto:{{ support_mail }}">{{ support_mail }}</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course it is a little bit more complex with translation, css and more than one block.

My wish is to define **invitation.txt**:

```
{% block message %}Dear {{ first_name|title }} {{ last_name|upper }},

Your inscription has bee accepted. Welcome!
{% endblock %}
```

I want to be able to load (body.txt, invitation.txt) and also (body.html, invitation.txt) to get my two html parts.

Edit:

Something like that:

**invitation/body.txt**:

```
{% extends body.txt invitation.txt %}
```

**invitation/body.html**:

```
{% extends body.html invitation.txt %}
```

Comment: Another idea: ``{% if html %}{% extends base.html %}{% else %}{% extends base.txt %}{% endif %}``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a variable in the context and pass it to `extends` template tag.

In invitation.txt:

```
{% extends base %}
{% block message %}Dear {{ first_name|title }} {{ last_name|upper }},

Your inscription has been accepted. Welcome!
{% endblock %}
```

Render invitation.txt with context `{'base': 'body.txt'}`, then with context `{'base': 'body.html'}`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include)

e.g.:
**invitation.txt**:

```
Dear {{ first_name|title }} {{ last_name|upper }},

Your inscription has bee accepted. Welcome!
```

**invitation/body.txt**:

```
{% extends body.txt %}
{% block message %}
{% include "invitation.txt" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**invitation/body.html**:

```
{% extends body.html %}
{% block message %}
{% include "invitation.txt" %}
{% endblock %}
```